# How to add jcompilo as a gradle dependency to android studio project

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio, repository

I am a beginner in maven, gradle and android studio (IntelliJ). I have recently downloaded the latest version of android studio and made a backend project where I want to use the jcompilo java compiler as a library from my code (compile java code from my program at run-time).

So I know the jcompilo project is located [here](http://repo.bodar.com/com/googlecode/jcompilo/jcompilo/202/), the problem is I don't know how to go about adding it as a dependency to my project in the recommended fashion.

My failed attempt thus far has been to include two new stanzas in my build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.bodar.com/com/googlecode/jcompilo"
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.googlecode.jcompilo:jcompilo:2'
}
```

I tried all sorts of naive variations such as removing parts of the paths, path separators, changing the version at the end to 2, 2.02, 2.0.2, 2+ etc, adding and removing the ":jcompilo" part at the end etc, exchanging "maven" with "ivy" etc to no avail. The error I get is mostly this:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.googlecode.jcompilo:jcompilo:2
```

So which of my assumptions are wrong, and how can I do this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right now I feel a bit silly because I found the answer just a minute after posting this from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/wiki/MavenRepository).

Anyways, to summarize, the repository could be used from gradle with the following stanzas in `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        //Notice the bare URL
        url "http://repo.bodar.com/"
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    //Notice the extended syntax
    compile group:'com.googlecode.jcompilo', name:'jcompilo', version:'202'
}
```

To be fair, I will leave this answer around for a while and accept any one that improves on it.

Again Thanks!

Comment: woops, beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The pom file in the repository that you link to claims that the version number is 202, not 2.0.2.
So try updating your dependency to:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "com.googlecode.jcompilo", name: "jcompilo", version: "202"
}
```